# Docker-compose: get linked container adress inside other container (in bash)

Tags: docker, sh, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm new to docker, so maybe it's a basic question, but i didn't find a proper answer for it.

I want to get elastic search adress as environment variable inside `start.sh` script. What is a proper way to do it not invasively, to not hardcode it ?

Docker compose:

```
version: "2"
services:
    #elasticsearch 
  elasticsearch: 
    container_name: es 
    volumes: 
      - ./elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data 
    extends: 
      file: ../../base-config-dev.yml 
      service: elasticsearch 

  es-sync:
    container_name: app-es-sync
    hostname: app-es-sync
    extends:
      file: ../../base-config-dev.yml
      service: es-sync
    links:
      - elasticsearch
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.4
MAINTAINER me@mail.com
RUN pip install mongo-connector==2.4.1 elastic2-doc-manager
RUN mkdir /opt/es-sync
COPY files/* /opt/es-sync/
RUN chmod 755 /opt/es-sync/start.sh
CMD exec /opt/es-sync/start.sh
```

start.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /opt/es-sync/
export LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8

python3 create_index.py ${ES_URI}

CONNECTOR_CONFIG="\
-m ${MONGO_URI} \
-t ${ES_URI} \
--oplog-ts=oplog.timestamp \
--batch-size=1 \
--verbose \
--continue-on-error \
--stdout \
--namespace-set=foo.bar \
--doc-manager elastic2_doc_manager"

echo "CONNECTOR_CONFIG: $CONNECTOR_CONFIG"

exec mongo-connector ${CONNECTOR_CONFIG}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using the Docker Compose `link` feature, you shouldn't have to do anything, you should be able to just use the hostname.

Since your link is defined as

```
links:
  - elasticsearch
```

you should be able to reach the elasticsearch container under the `elasticsearch` hostname.

If you try a `ping elasticsearch` from inside of the `es-sync` container, the hostname should be resolved and reachable from there.

Then you just need to turn that into a URL (it looks like you're looking for that): `http://elasticsearch:9200/` (assuming that it's running on port 9200).

Comment: Is it so simple ? edit: i've tried to refer as `ES_URI=http://elasticsearch:9200` and getting `Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused` from python script

Comment: Are you sure that elasticsearch is running on port 9200? Please verify the port...

Comment: And are you sure it's up and running when you're trying to connect? Also networks are preferable to links, but get it working first I guess ;)

Comment: in `../../base-config-dev.yml ` elasticsearch has `ports: - "9200:9200"  - "9300:9300"` and in python file i'm calling ES using urllib2

Comment: I think `urllib2` needs exact ip adress with schema, host and port. It there a way to get that by `elasticsearch` link ? edit: in `start.sh` if I place `ping -c 4 elasticsearch` I can see that it's reachable